# Laravel validation OR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

I have some validation that requires a url *or* a route to be there but **not** both.

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'  =>  'required|max:255',
        'url'   =>  'required_without_all:route|url',
        'route' =>  'required_without_all:url|route',
        'parent_items'=>  'sometimes|required|integer'
    ]);
```

I have tried using `required_without` and `required_without_all` however they both get past the validation and I am not sure why.

`route` is a rule in the `route` field

Comment: I just tried using `required_without` and it works. Can you post your `route` rule? `return ['route' => "required_without:url", 'url' => "required_without:route|url"];` Works as expected for me.

Comment: @BenSwinburne See the answer below and my comment, required is totally the wrong thing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be creation your own validation rule. It could looks like.

```
Validator::extend('empty_if', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator) {

    $fields = $validator->getData(); //data passed to your validator

    foreach($parameters as $param) {
        $excludeValue = array_get($fields, $param, false);

        if($excludeValue) { //if exclude value is present validation not passed
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

And use it

```
    $this->validate($request, [
    'name'  =>  'required|max:255',
    'url'   =>  'empty_if:route|url',
    'route' =>  'empty_if:url|route',
    'parent_items'=>  'sometimes|required|integer'
]);
```

P.S. Don't forget to register this in your provider.

**Edit**

Add custom message

1) Add message
2) Add replacer

```
Validator::replacer('empty_if', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
    $replace = [$attribute, $parameters[0]];
    //message is: The field :attribute cannot be filled if :other is also filled
    return  str_replace([':attribute', ':other'], $replace, $message);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I realized this morning that required_if isn't what I needed at all and is in fact to check if _another_ field is empty, appreciate your help

Comment: There is a slight problem with the rule regarding messages, due to it being a custom validation rule it doesn't do the same replaces in the messages, and if I just set it as a static message then it will appear twice due to both fields using the same role, would you be able to extend your answer to include the message? For example `The field :attribute cannot be filled if :other is also filled"?` The closest I have tracked down the method is in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php` line 1680

Comment: perfect yet again! I thought it may have something to do with the 3rd parameter of `$this->validate()` but nope, thank you! :)

Answer (score 13):

I think you are looking for [`required_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-if):

> The field under validation must be present if the *anotherfield* field is equal to any value.

So, the validation rule would be:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name'        =>  'required|max:255',
    'url'         =>  'required_if:route,""',
    'route'       =>  'required_if:url,""',
    'parent_items'=>  'sometimes|required|integer'
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help, validation still passes when both fields are filled

Comment: @Ian Just a thought: Why don't you use jQuery ? For instance, if a user is filling `url` field, then add `readonly` attribute to `route` field and vice versa. In that way, they will NOT be able to fill the data if one of the field is filled in.

Comment: Well they can just remove that attribute and it will still go through server side, jQuery is **not** a solution to a server side problem