# Several validation rules with "OR" condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the *MyRequest class*, which contain validation rules for request params. In the "file" field can be **null** or **string** or **file**. How I can build the rule conditions for it?

```
class MyRequest extends FormRequest
// ...
   public function rules()
        {
            return [
                 // 'file' => 'image|max:20480', // need to combine this
                 // 'file' => 'nullable|string', // and this through OR
                 // 'file' => 'nullable|string|image|max:20480' // <- don't working (string not pass validation)
            ];
         }
}
```

I also made my own rule:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('myCustomRule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return !Validator::make([$attribute => $value], ['nullable|image|max:20480'])->fails()
                || !Validator::make([$attribute => $value], ['string'])->fails();
        });
    }
```

and it did not work. The idea is that I want to use the Laravel rules, and not to write my own implementation of the rules for checking the string length, etc.

Comment: Create Custom Validation Rule.

Comment: But how? and in what place? I tried to do it, but I did not find how to use the two already prepared Laravel rules through OR. Only just how to write my entire string length check, etc. @Bugfixer

Comment: This will help http://www.expertphp.in/article/how-to-create-custom-validation-rules-with-laravel-5

Comment: @Bugfixer Yes, thanks, I saw this article, but I do not want to write substr($value, 0, 3). I want to write inside my rule something like `nullable|string` || `image|max:20480`, understand?

Comment: Who told you to write substr ? you can code your own rule with conditions and if condition is satisfied return true else false.

Comment: @Bugfixer I say substr, for example, like in the article. In my case, I wrote that: `public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('myFileRule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return !Validator::make([$attribute => $value], ['nullable|image|max:20480'])->fails()
                || !Validator::make([$attribute => $value], ['string'])->fails();
        });
    }` and its don't work

Comment: update this in your quesion.

Comment: @Bugfixer done.

Comment: @nilecrocodile Here is a good article that might assist your cause (and also suggested the required_if usage): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915547/laravel-validation-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It works (Laravel v5.4):

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
// ...
    public function boot()
    {
    Validator::extend('myCustomRule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

            $validator1 = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], [
                'image' => 'nullable|string|max:255'
            ]);

            $validator2 = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], [
                'image' => 'image|max:20480'
            ]);

            return !$validator1->fails() || !$validator2->fails();
        });
// ...
```