# Laravel custom rule if previous rules passed

Tags: laravel, rules

In Request `rules()` I have

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'files' => ['nullable', 'array'],
        'files.*' => ['file','max:256000', new PostFiles],
        'body' => 'nullable|string',
        'public' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

I need `PostFiles` rule be executed only if all other checks regarding file are passed.
Now I am getting error if I will send instead file array of strings and I don't want to duplicate `'file','max:256000'` check in `PostFiles` in `passes(){}` method.

Laravel 7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915547/laravel-validation-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution:

just add `bail`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).